# Save values from foreach loop in wp_editor

Tags: wp-editor, post-meta, customization

I have created a custom metabox that contains a wp_editor.
The wp_editor shows content of a uploaded .csv file and constructs a table.
I want to allow the users to edit the table after uploading the .csv file.

This works. Now I want to make it a little bit more advanced.
So I added the possibility to upload multiple .csv files.
This also works. The problem is the saving of the wp_editors.
wp_editor states that every editor should have it's own editor_id.
see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

I can add a number??? to the editor_id but the problem is saving/updating the content.

I do this with a save function.
 See below what I did.
This is the foreach loop checking how many .csv files there are and constructs a wp_editor everytime it comes across one:

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mcu', true);
$get_url = unserialize ($value);
foreach ($get_url as $list) {
        echo '<p style="margin:50px 0 0 0;">';
        echo '<strong>'.$list.'</strong>';
        ob_start();
        jj_readcsv($list,true);
        $link = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $editor_id = 'my_uploaded_csv';

        wp_editor( $link, $editor_id );
        echo '</p>';
    }
```

Here is a basic save function for the wp_editor. I can't seem to figure out how I can make this have a foreach loop to so I can save/update all the data.

```
function save_wp_editor_fields(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_uploaded_csv', $_POST['my_uploaded_csv']);
}
```

I hope anyone can assist me with this.

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_editor` function accepts `(array) $settings` param and that one can contain `textarea_name` as a key. If it's not being specified, it's set by default as `$editor_id`. See: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c392ff6f90d550bad876d8a984ad6b3b8a49cd96/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L44

So you might want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($get_url as $list) {
    ...
    $settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'uploaded_csv[]' );
    ...
    wp_editor( $link, $editor_id, $settings );
    ...
}
```

And in your saving function, you simply loop over the `$_POST['uploaded_csv']` array

```
function save_wp_editor_fields(){
    global $post;
    foreach ( $_POST['uplaoded_csv'] as $key => $uploaded_csv ) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_uploaded_csv_'.$key, $uploaded_csv);
    }
}
```

Of course you should figure out the uniqueness of the created meta (eg. giving it a number or handle more meta keys per post with non unique name. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta).

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Yes that worked. Thnx for the explanation also. It's always nice to understand what you're doing. FYI: I gave the editor_id a number.